# How do I send file in a PUT resquest using Postman

Tags: json, httprequest, put, postman, raw-data

I using postman to test my api, and I need to send a PUT request that has a json object and some files. Im sending raw data to test this but I cant seem to figure out how to add a file in there.

PUT request 
raw data example:

```
{ 
   "email": "someone@something.com",
   "info": "new account",
   "file1" : (some file should be here),
   "file2": (some file should be here)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to send files AND data in a PUT request, either the body of the request IS a file content, either you use POST to have multiple files of a file with other data.

I honestly can't explain more as I am stucked with the same kind of problem :-)